# Floating Social Icons attached to content

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu, icons, floating

Im trying to add floating social icons to my wordpress website (using the wp bootstrap starter theme). Im using the following css:

```
.social{  
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: fixed;
right: -130px;
top:13rem;
width:210px;
z-index: 99;  
}

.menu-social-container .social li{
list-style-type: none;
color: #fff;
height: 43px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 1px 0;
}

.menu-social-container .social li a{
display: block;
max-width: 40px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

and (end of) header.php

```
</header><!-- #masthead -->
<div id="content" class="site-content">

    <div class="container">
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social', 'menu_class' => 'social' ) ); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php endif; ?>

</header><!-- #masthead -->
<div id="content" class="site-content">
```

From Firefox:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="menu-social-container">
<ul id="menu-social" class="social">
<li id="menu-item-347" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-347"><a href="http://index.php"><i class="fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-348" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-348"><a href="http://index.php"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-349" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-349"><a href="http://index.php"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-350" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-350"><a href="http://index.php"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-351" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-351"><a href="http://index.php"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
```

Everything is working fine, but I want the icons to be attached to the content area (just beside it) and not to the far right side of the browser. Because depending on the browser/device size the icons are either miles away from the content and not noticable or right above the content.

I appreciate any help.